# chart js stripline? like one from canvas

Tags: charts, chart.js

hello how to give different color at 30 point on this jsfiddle i post my code also
i know stripline in canvas js did but in chart js cant figure it out thank you.
[here is fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/Luaf2tm4/568/)
. I want to give different color at 30 and explain answers.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');

var data = {
    labels: ["D", "I", "S", "C"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Оноо",
            borderWidth: 2,
            hoverBorderColor: "grey",
            data: [40, 20, 35, 25],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.5)',
                'rgba(247, 220, 111, 0.5)',
                'rgba(130, 224, 170, 0.5)',
                'rgba(93, 173, 226, 0.5)',

            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor:['rgba(231, 76, 60, 1)','rgba(247, 220, 111, 1)',  'rgba(130, 224, 170, 1)',   'rgba(93, 173, 226, 1)'],
            yAxes:{
            stripLines:[
            {       
                    color:'red',
              value:30,
              thickness:3
            }
            ]                    
        },
        }
    ]
};
var option = {
    scales: {
    yAxes:[{
            stacked:true,
        gridLines: {
            display:true,
          color:"rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"
        }
    }],
    xAxes:[{
            gridLines: {
            display:false
        }
    }]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using a ChartJS plugin called - [**chartjs-plugin-annotation**](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation).

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');

var data = {
   labels: ["D", "I", "S", "C"],
   datasets: [{
      label: "Оноо",
      borderWidth: 2,
      hoverBorderColor: "grey",
      data: [40, 20, 35, 25],
      backgroundColor: [
         'rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.5)',
         'rgba(247, 220, 111, 0.5)',
         'rgba(130, 224, 170, 0.5)',
         'rgba(93, 173, 226, 0.5)',
      ],
      hoverBackgroundColor: ['rgba(231, 76, 60, 1)', 'rgba(247, 220, 111, 1)', 'rgba(130, 224, 170, 1)', 'rgba(93, 173, 226, 1)'],
   }]
};
var option = {
   scales: {
      yAxes: [{
         stacked: true,
         gridLines: {
            display: true,
            color: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"
         }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
         gridLines: {
            display: false
         }
      }]
   },
   annotation: {
      annotations: [{
         type: 'line',
         drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
         id: 'strip-line-1',
         mode: 'horizontal',
         scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
         value: 30,
         borderColor: 'red',
         borderWidth: 3
      }]
   }
};


var myBarChart = new Chart(canvas, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: data,
   options: option
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/0.5.7/chartjs-plugin-annotation.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

To learn more about this plugin and it­*'s* use-cases, refer [here](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation#configuration).

Comment: superb thank you so do i need to add annotation plugin into my html yeah?

Comment: i am not familier with chart js as you can see there is only 1 bar in here how to add 4 of them on top

Comment: Yes you need to add annotation plugin in your HTML.

Comment: and, that's a different question and has nothing to do with annotation plugin. you should rather post a new question with adequate details for that, than asking it in the comment section.